# can't find template "Consume Adapter Service"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk

After creating a new BizTalk project, I chose to Add New Item to my project.  To trigger the WCF-SQL adapter wizard, I want to choose Consume Adapter Service there. Like in this tutorial: http://btsguru.blogspot.com/2012/01/debatching-inbound-messages-from-wcf.html

Problem is I don't have that template, I only got:
- Add adapter metadata
- Generate schemas
- Consume WCF service

I've installed the adapter pack.

Any idea why this is missing or how I get it installed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the WCF LOB adapter pack and the BizTalk WCF SQL adapter separately.

Comment: I had to remove the already installed WCF LOB adapter pack and then reinstall it, seems like there was some version problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the [WCF Adapter SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22067).

Comment: I've tried to install both but the template is still missing in Visual Studio 2010